# Как в Web Socket передать сообщение с custom name

Tags: javascript, websocket

Подскажите пожалуйста.
У меня есть серверная и клиентская часть написанная на Web Socket.

На сервере я поставил две функции

```
   ws.on('message', function(message) {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({test:'dddddddddddd'}))
        console.log('получено сообщение ' + message);
    });
    ws.on('test', function(message) {
        console.log('получено сообщение ' + message);
    });
```

На клиенте я поставил два обработчика событий

```
socket['socket'].addEventListener('test', function (event) {

    console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!test!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
  });
socket['socket'].addEventListener('message', function (event) {

  console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!message!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
});
```

Как мне послать сообщениена обработчик ws.on('test') ?

Метод send всегда посылает запросы на  ws.on('message')...

```
   socket['socket'].send(JSON.stringify({socket:'message'}));

   socket['socket'].send(JSON.stringify({socket:'???test???'}));
```

Comment: Никак, потому что любые сообщения всегда приходят только по событию message. Что вам мешает отфильтровать всё что надо внутри обработчика message?

Comment: ничего не мешает. так и сделаю.